# Main Fragment Overlaps with child fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to make a basic Countdown app.

Below is my main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.dot.timer.MainActivity">


    <Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.dot.timer.SetTimer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chronometer" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have created two fragments

1)SetTimer.java\fragment_set_timer.xml [With a EditText and Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw568.png)

2)TimerButtons.java\fragment_timer_buttons.xml [Three Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Y40.png)

SetTimer Activity is below

```
  public class SetTimer extends Fragment{
  View view;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_set_timer, container, false);

    Button button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft =fm.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment=new TimerButtons();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment,fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}}
```

SetTimer xml is below

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.dot.timer.SetTimer">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Set"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     />
     </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

  </FrameLayout>
```

When i run the project and click on Set Button 
[this is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55XV8.png)

and background frame is even Clickable
but shouldn't using .replace() destroy previous fragment

Why is it happening and how can i correct it?

Comment: post `setTimer fragment xml code`

Comment: added setTimer fragment xml code

Comment: @S added setTimer xml